# Can't declare ifstream class member in header file

Tags: c++, ifstream, private-members

I am trying to declare an ifstream object in a header file as is shown but I get an error saying that it cannot be accessed.  I have tried various things such as making it into a pointer instead, initialising in the .c file etc. but my code can't seem to get part the declaration of it.

ReadFile.h:

```
#ifndef READFILE_H
#define READFILE_H

#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class ReadFile{

private:
    std::ifstream stream;

public:
    std::string read();

    ReadFile();                                 // Default constructor
    ~ReadFile();                                    // Destructor
};

#endif
```

ReadFile.c:
    #include "ReadFile.h"

```
ReadFile::ReadFile(){
stream.open("./data.txt");
}

ReadFile::~ReadFile(){
stream.close();
}
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
Error   9   error C2248: 'std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ifstream' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>' c:\users\Bob\documents\project\models\readfile.h    23  1   Project
```

The output is:

```
1>c:\users\Bob\documents\project\models\readfile.h(23): error C2248: 'std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ifstream' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\fstream(827) : see declaration of 'std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ifstream'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'ReadFile::ReadFile(const ReadFile &)'
```

The error occurs when `std::ifstream stream;` is included and will disappear when this line is removed.  What could be causing this error?  Have I missed something really obvious or is there more to it?

Comment: That's odd, the error message says the problem is at line 23, but the file only has 21 lines. Could it be that this isn't the file that caused the problem?

Comment: I took a couple of functions that were't relevant to the issue out of the header file just to simplify things and forgot that would mess up the line numbers, sorry about that.  Line 23 is actually the one with `};` on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `std::ifstream` doesn't have a public copy constructor (because copying one wouldn't make sense) but the compiler-generated copy constructor for your class wants to use it.

It doesn't have any available assignment operator for the same reason (i.e. copying a `std::ifstream` is nonsense).

You should disallow copying and assignment for your class as well.

A simple way is to add

```
private:
    ReadFile(const ReadFile&);
    ReadFile& operator=(const ReadFile&);
```

to your class, if you're using C++03.

In C++11, use the `= delete` syntax.

```
public:
    ReadFile(const ReadFile&) = delete;
    ReadFile& operator=(const ReadFile&) = delete;
```

Comment: I would simply provide a private declaration, that's enough to forbid it; no need to give it a body. Also the assignment operator should be forbidden always along the copy constructor (it will be also compiler generated otherwise).

Comment: `ReadFile(const ReadFile&) = delete;` if you're the C++11 kind

Comment: Ok I added the copy constructor declaration under private and got the error `'ReadFile::ReadFile' : cannot access private member declared in class 'ReadFile'` so I tried putting it under public and it worked fine.  Is there any reason in particular that you say to make it private?  Also what do you mean by "the assignment operator should be forbidden always along the copy constructor"?  Is this something I need to set or do you mean to just avoid using the assignment operator?

Comment: @Riddle: Then you are copying a `ReadFile` instance somewhere, which is not advisable. The point of making the copy constructor and copy assignment operator private is so that you get the very compiler error you got if an instance of the class is copied accidentally.

Comment: Is this a compiler bug? If I'm interpreting http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Deleted_implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator correctly, `ReadFile`'s implicitly-declared copy constructor should automatically be defined as deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer per se, but in case anyone comes across this question in the future after struggling as much as I just have, I decided to post it anyway.

I was facing a very similar issue to the OP for basically the same reason, although the error message that Visual C++ was giving me was `'ClassName::ClassName(const ClassName &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`. In my inexperienced mind, I was thinking "WTF, I'm not copying or assigning any copies anywhere!".

However, after an hour of screaming at the computer in frustration I was able to narrow the problem down to the `ifstream` class member, which led me here. And thanks to the accepted answer, I was able to narrow the problem down even further to this single line of code:

```
list.emplace_back(objParam);
```

Little did I know that `std::vector` objects need a copy constructor defined on their template parameter's type in order to reserve space for future `emplace_back()` calls and the like!

So the solution comes from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457302/c-vector-emplace-back-calls-copy-constructor#answer-40457433) courtesy of Bryan Chen (emphasis added by me):

> So you can see emplace_back does use the desired constructor to create the element and call copy constructor when it need to grow the storage. **You can call reserve with enough capacity upfront to avoid the need to call copy constructor**.

Full credit and many thanks go to Bryan and molbdnilo for leading me to this discovery.