# C++ vector emplace_back calls copy constructor

Tags: c++, vector, std

This is a demo class. I do not want my class to be copied, so I delete the copy constructor. I want vector.emplace_back to use this constructor 'MyClass(Type type)'. But these codes won't compile. Why?

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    typedef enum
    {
        e1,
        e2
    } Type;
private:
    Type _type;
    MyClass(const MyClass& other) = delete; // no copy
public:
    MyClass(): _type(e1) {};
    MyClass(Type type): _type(type) { /* the constructor I wanted. */ };
};

std::vector<MyClass> list;
list.emplace_back(MyClass::e1);
list.emplace_back(MyClass::e2);
```

Comment: To fix the problem, add a defaulted move constructor. If you don't want movable either then your options are more limited

Comment: Thanks, I choose to write a move constructor.

Comment: @M.M comment *is* the answer!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The copy constructor is required by `vector` so that it can copy the element when it need to grow its storage.

You can read the document for [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

> T must meet the requirements of CopyAssignable and
>   **CopyConstructible**.    (until C++11)
>
> The requirements that are imposed on
>   the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the
>   container. Generally, it is required that element type is a complete
>   type and meets the requirements of Erasable, but many member functions
>   impose stricter requirements. (since C++11) (until C++17)
>
> The
>   requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual
>   operations performed on the container. Generally, it is required that
>   element type meets the requirements of Erasable, but many member
>   functions impose stricter requirements. This container (but not its
>   members) can be instantiated with an incomplete element type if the
>   allocator satisfies the allocator completeness requirements.

Some logging can help you understand what's going on

[For this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96548d2dfa43a3c4)

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    typedef enum
    {
        e1 = 1,
        e2 = 2,
        e3 = 3,
    } Type;
private:
    Type _type;
public:
    MyClass(Type type): _type(type) { std::cout << "create " << type << "\n"; };
    MyClass(const MyClass& other) { std::cout << "copy " << other._type << "\n"; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<MyClass> list;
    list.reserve(2);
    list.emplace_back(MyClass::e1);
    list.emplace_back(MyClass::e2);
    list.emplace_back(MyClass::e3);
}
```

The output is

```
create 1
create 2
create 3
copy 1
copy 2
```

So you can `emplace_back` does use the desired constructor to create the element and call copy constructor when it need to grow the storage. You can call `reserve` with enough capacity upfront to avoid the need to call copy constructor.

---

If for some reason you really don't want it to be copy constructible, you can use `std::list` instead of `std::vector` as `list` is implemented as linked list, it doesn't need to move the elements.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16f93cfc6b2fc73c

Comment: You bolded a part of the pre-C++11 behaviour. The rest of your quote explains that the behaviour changed in C++11, in particular the bolded part no longer applies.

Comment: @Bryan Chen I think you mean this http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2dea811906d90d84

Answer (score 7):

Just a precision for the issue. If we don't want objects copy construction to be used when a reallocation of the container occurs, it is indeed possible with a move constructor but only if it has the noexcept specification.

Containers refuse to move construct elements if the constructor might throw an exception because it could lead to a container in a bad state that cannot be cleaned. That's the reason why it is generally a good practice to specify a move constructor as noexcept when we are sure it will never throw any exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back, the `value_type` of a `std::vector<T>` needs to be [MoveInsertable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveInsertable) and [EmplaceConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/EmplaceConstructible). *MoveInsertable* in particular requires a move constructor or a copy constructor.

So, if you don't want your class to be copied, you should add an explicit move constructor. You can use `= default` to use the compiler-provided default implementation that just moves all fields.

### Full example

```cpp
#include <vector>

class MyClass
{
public:
    typedef enum
    {
        e1,
        e2
    } Type;
private:
    Type _type;
    MyClass(const MyClass& other) = delete; // no copy
public:
    MyClass(): _type(e1) {};
    MyClass(MyClass&&) noexcept = default; // < the new move constructor
    MyClass(Type type): _type(type) { /* the constructor I wanted. */ };
};

int main() {
    std::vector<MyClass> list;
    list.emplace_back(MyClass::e1);
    list.emplace_back(MyClass::e2);
}
```

### Note

Note that you can get a very confusing

> `error: use of deleted function ‘MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass&)`

with C++17 when you use

```cpp
auto x = list.emplace_back(MyClass::e1);
```

instead of

```cpp
auto& x = list.emplace_back(MyClass::e1);
```

even with the move constructor.

Comment: Thank you for that extra note I was going nuts "why is `emplace_back` trying to call my deleted copy constructor?!?"