# I have a problem creating a vector of blocking queues in C++

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors, queue, g++

I'm trying to write a simple program that creates and uses a certain number (variable - it is a parameter passed by command line) of blocking queues. To easily access them, I thought about creating a vector of queues.

I'm using g++-8 to compile the program. The queue I have is provided by my professor, so I can't make any changes in its code.

Here is the code I've developed:

blocking_queue.hpp

```cpp
    #ifndef SKYLINE_BLOCKING_QUEUE_HPP
    #define SKYLINE_BLOCKING_QUEUE_HPP

    #include <iostream>
    #include <mutex>
    #include <condition_variable>
    #include <deque>
    #include <vector>
    #include <chrono>
    #include <cstddef>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <thread>


    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

    //
    // needed a blocking queue
    // here is a sample queue.
    //

    template <typename T>
    class blocking_queue
    {
    private:
    std::mutex d_mutex;
    std::condition_variable d_condition;
    std::deque<T> d_queue;
    public:

    blocking_queue(){}

    void push(T const& value) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->d_mutex);
            d_queue.push_front(value);
        }
        this->d_condition.notify_one();
    }

    T pop() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->d_mutex);
        this->d_condition.wait(lock, [=]{return !this->d_queue.empty(); });
        T rc(std::move(this->d_queue.back()));
        this->d_queue.pop_back();
        return rc;
    }

    bool is_empty() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->d_mutex);
        this->d_condition.wait(lock, [=]{return !this->d_queue.empty(); });
        printf("ADDED A INT\n");
        return false;
    }

    int size() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->d_mutex);
        return(d_queue.size());
    }

    };

    #endif // SKYLINE_BLOCKING_QUEUE_HPP
```

test.cpp

```cpp
    int main(char argc, char* argv[]) {
        nw = atoi(argv[0]);
        vector<blocking_queue<int>> myVector;

        for(int i = 0; i < nw; i++) {
            myVector.emplace_back();             
        }

    }
```

When I try to compile the program, g++ gives me the following error:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘blocking_queue<int>::blocking_queue(blocking_queue<int>&&)’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./test.cpp:10:
./blocking_queue.hpp:28:7: note: ‘blocking_queue<int>::blocking_queue(blocking_queue<int>&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class blocking_queue
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./blocking_queue.hpp:28:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex&)’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/mutex:43,
                 from ./blocking_queue.hpp:9,
                 from ./test.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/std_mutex.h:97:5: note: declared here
     mutex(const mutex&) = delete;
     ^~~~~
In file included from ./test.cpp:10:
./blocking_queue.hpp:28:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::condition_variable::condition_variable(const std::condition_variable&)’
 class blocking_queue
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Unrelated but I'd change `this->d_condition.wait(lock, [=]{return !this->d_queue.empty(); });` to `while(d_queue.empty()) d_condition.wait(lock);`. If the queue is not empty there's no need to go into the wait. Also: "_The implicit capture of `*this` when the capture default is = is deprecated since C++20_"

Comment: And your `is_empty()` function is flawed. It waits for it to not be empty instead of returning `true` if it is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply need to create a vector of `nw` elements you can do the following:

```
std::vector<blocking_queue<int>> myVector(nw);
```

The use of `emplace_back` could work, but when doing `emplace_back` the `vector` might need to resize and resize might trigger copies between old buffer and new buffer. See [C++ vector emplace_back calls copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457302/c-vector-emplace-back-calls-copy-constructor) . As far as I know if you have a `noexcept` move ctor, the `vector` will use it instead of copying but I do not know if this is a guaranteed optimization from the standard of something that an implementor could choose to do. Regardless, your class does not seem to be movable, because of some of its members, namely `condition_variable` and `mutex`.
So using this particular object inside a vector could be problematic, depends on your use case.

If you need to be able to resize your container you can:

1. Keep `vector` and use `unique_ptr` of the `queue` object to store elements inside the vector
2. Use `std::list` that should not require to copy objects when resizing because it is a linked list.

In both cases you might lose performance

Comment: I tried this way and it compiles, but at runtime, when the program tries to create the vector, gives me the following error:
```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
      what(): std::bad_alloc
   aborted
```

Comment: Weird, what value of nw are you using? What are you doing after the creation of the vector?

Comment: @Carmine For one, that can't be your real code (or if it is, it's certainly broken). `argv[0]` is the process name, not the first argument, so `atoi(argv[0])` is certainly busted. You should be checking `argc >= 2`, then using `atoi(argv[1])` for that call. (and frankly, you shouldn't even be doing that, as `atoi` error "reporting" is pathetic; better to use `std::stol` or something similar).

Comment: @Carmine most likely WhozCraig is right, suggestion, drop atoi and hardcode nw to 10 (like I did in my test) and see.

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you! I do as you said and I've resolved the problem. In the simplification of the problem, I miscopied that part and obviously, it's not `argv[0]` but `argv[1]`. Obviously in my program I already do all the tests on the `argc` and on the various `argv`s

Answer (score 0):

Try using `emplace_back()` instead of `push_back()`.

`push_back()` uses the copy constructor, which seems to have been deleted.