# C++ vector of objects of custom class - copy constructor deleted - std::ifstream

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, copy-constructor, ifstream

I'm trying to create a vector of objects of a custom class A:

```
class A {
    std::ifstream _file;
    std::string _fileName;
public:
    A(std::string &fileName) : _fileName(fileName) {
        this->_file = std::ifstream(this->_fileName, std::ios::in);
    }
    ~A() {
        this->_file.close();
    }
};
```

In the main I'm pushing n objects of class A with a for loop iterating a vector of file names.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "A.hpp"

int main() {

    std::vector<A> AList;
    std::vector<std::string> fileList = { "file1", "file2", "file3" };

    for (auto &f : fileList) {
        std::cout << f << std::endl;
        A tempObj(f);
        AList.emplace_back(tempObj);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But I get this error:
`/usr/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(const A&)’`

If I'm not wrong, since I have a member std::ifstream inside my class A, the copy constructor is deleted (Ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream)

How can I solve it? What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your code doesn't compile for other reasons. One is that you're calling `emplace_back` on `filesList` (a misspelling of `fileList`) when you should be calling that on `AList`. You need to give us a minimal example that fully reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I added more correct code in order to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the other answer, `class A` is non-copyable because its member `std::ifstream _file;` is non-copyable.

But `std::ifstream` is movable, and normally your class would be movable as well, *but* providing a custom destructor prevents the implicit generation of a move constructor and a move assignment operator (see the chart [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38687106/2752075)).

So, step 1: Make your class movable by removing the custom destructor (the implicitly generated destructor will do the same thing anyway).

Alternatively, if you want to keep the destructor for some reason, you need to ask your compiler to generate a move constructor and a move assignment operator:

```
A(A &&) = default;
A &operator=(A &&) = default;
```

Step 2: When adding an instance of `class A` to the vector, move it instead of copying:

```
A tempObj(f);
AList.emplace_back(std::move(tempObj));
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^       ^
```

Alternatively, construct it directly in the vector:

```
AList.emplace_back(f);
```

Answer (score 5):

Like you said, your `A` class is not copyable due to the `ifstream` member, which can't be copied. So your class's copy constructor is deleted by default.
But you are trying to copy-construct an `A` object when you pass `tempFile` to  `emplace_back()`.

You need to pass the filename instead to `emplace_back()` and let it construct the `A` object inside the vector for you by forwarding the string to your constructor:

```cpp
std::vector<A> AList;
std::vector<std::string> fileList;

for (auto &f : fileList)
{
    AList.emplace_back(f);
}
```

On a side note, your constructor can and should initialize the `ifstream` in the *member initialization list* rather than in the constructor body:

```cpp
A::A(std::string &fileName)
    : _file(fileName), _fileName(fileName)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I get the same error. 

`/usr/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(const A&)’
   75 |     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

I tried with this code:
`int main() {

 std::vector<A> AList;
 std::vector<std::string> fileList = { "file1", "file2", "file3" };

 for (auto &f : fileList) {
  std::cout << f << std::endl;
  AList.emplace_back(f);
 }

 return 0;
}`

Comment: See [C++ vector emplace_back calls copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457302/). Add a move constructor to your class to fix the error, like gimme_danger's answer shows

Answer (score 1):

> If I'm not wrong, since I have a member std::ifstream inside my class A, the copy constructor is deleted (Ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream)

You are right, `std::basic_ifstream` is an example of uncopyable type, because it's illogical to have several copies of a single stream. In this situation you should use move semantics. Just add [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) to your class definition:

```
A(A&& other) noexcept 
  : _file(move(other._file))
  , _fileName(move(other._fileName))
{}
```

And now your code works [fine](https://godbolt.org/), because vector elements are properly constructed during pushing:

```
std::vector<A> AList;
for (auto &f : { "file1", "file2", "file3" })
  AList.push_back(A(f));
```